# Rails: Nested Forms - passing the user_id from parent to child

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to pass the user_id from the parent model (**Order**) to the child model (**Sale**). As this does not work the "normal" way, like `@sale.user_id = current_user.id` (this actually works for the parent model `Order` with `@order.user_id = current_user.id`). I tried this in my model as a workaround:

```
class Sale < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
  before_create :user

  def user
    self.user_id = Order.where(:id => self.order_id).pluck(:user_id)
  end

end
```

Within `user` I'm comparing the **Order**.id (parent) with the **Sale**.order_id (child) as the `order_id` gets saved within a Sale record. When I look up the last Sale record, the `user_id` is always `nil`.

```
class SalesController < ApplicationController
 load_and_authorize_resource
 before_action :authenticate_user!

 def create
   @order = Order.find(params[:order_id])
   @sale = @order.sales.create(params[:sale].permit(:product, :product_group, :discount, :order_id, :user_id, :multiplier))
   redirect_to order_path(@order)
 end
```

Do you have an Idea?

Comment: Where is the code in which you are creating `Sale` and `Order` records?

Comment: Sorry. Just added the SalesController. Order is not relevant imho, as everything works there.

Comment: Where are you creating Order records? Please confirm if your order records really have `user_id` column filled correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your model.

```
 def user
   self.user_id = self.order.user_id
 end
```

Comment: simple as that! Thank you @Harry Bomrah

Comment: @Harakiri no problem at all .. :)

Answer (score 1):

> params[:sale].permit(:product, :product_group, :discount, **:order_id**, **:user_id**, :multiplier)

Firstly, you should **not permit** `user_id` & `order_id` in your controller.

Secondly, you can populate your Sale's `user_id` as follow:

```
def user
  user_id = order.user_id
end
```